# How to print elements of particular RDD partition in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

How to print the elements of a particular partition, say 5th, alone?

```
val distData = sc.parallelize(1 to 50, 10)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using Spark/Scala:

```
val data = 1 to 50
val distData = sc.parallelize(data,10)
distData.mapPartitionsWithIndex( (index: Int, it: Iterator[Int]) =>it.toList.map(x => if (index ==5) {println(x)}).iterator).collect
```

produces:

```
26
27
28
29
30
```

Comment: What would be python equivalent of it?

Comment: not sure why, but when i try executing the above come in spark-shell terminal, the output is simply an array of empty elements. Any ideas?

Comment: got it. the last statement shouldn't simply println(x) which would return nothing to the output RDD and hence produce nothing on the console. You can instead have simply x : distData.mapPartitionsWithIndex( (index: Int, it: Iterator[Int]) =>it.toList.map(x => if (index ==5) {x}).iterator).collect

Comment: The above output of the answer will be produced exactly with this line. Try this 
distData.mapPartitionsWithIndex( (index: Int, it: Iterator[Int]) =>it.toList.map(x => if (index ==5) {x} else "S").iterator).filter(x=>x!="S").collect.foreach(x=>print(x+" "))

Answer (score 4):

Assume you do this just for test purpose, then use glom(). See Spark documentation: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.glom

```
>>> rdd = sc.parallelize([1, 2, 3, 4], 2)
>>> rdd.glom().collect()
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
>>> rdd.glom().collect()[1]
[3, 4]
```

Edit: Example in Scala:

```
scala> val distData = sc.parallelize(1 to 50, 10)
scala> distData.glom().collect()(4)
res2: Array[Int] = Array(21, 22, 23, 24, 25)
```

Answer (score 2):

you could possible use a counter against foreachPartition() API to achieve it.

Here is a Java program that prints content of each partition
                JavaSparkContext context = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

```
    JavaRDD<Integer> myArray = context.parallelize(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9));
    JavaRDD<Integer> partitionedArray = myArray.repartition(2);

    System.out.println("partitioned array size is " + partitionedArray.count());
    partitionedArray.foreachPartition(new VoidFunction<Iterator<Integer>>() {

        public void call(Iterator<Integer> arg0) throws Exception {

            while(arg0.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(arg0.next());
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: i have already tried 'foreachPartition()' , it didnt print any element