# How to get data from a specific partition in Spark RDD?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I want to access data from a particular partition in Spark RDD.
I can get address of a partition as follow:

```
myRDD.partitions(0)
```

But I want to get data from `myRDD.partitions(0)` partition.
I tried official org.apache.spark documentation but couldn't find.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to print elements of particular RDD partition in Spark?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30077425/how-to-print-elements-of-particular-rdd-partition-in-spark)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `mapPartitionsWithIndex` as follows

```scala
// Create (1, 1), (2, 2), ..., (100, 100) dataset
// and partition by key so we know what to expect
val rdd = sc.parallelize((1 to 100) map (i => (i, i)), 16)
  .partitionBy(new org.apache.spark.HashPartitioner(8))

val zeroth = rdd
  // If partition number is not zero ignore data
  .mapPartitionsWithIndex((idx, iter) => if (idx == 0) iter else Iterator())

// Check if we get expected results 8, 16, ..., 96
assert (zeroth.keys.map(_ % 8 == 0).reduce(_ & _) & zeroth.count == 12)
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use `glom()` function which goes through each partition and gets all elements into array and then returns new RDD of arrays of elements of each partition where each array is separate partition.

Let's say we have rdd with data spreading among 5 partitions:

```scala
val rdd = sc.parallelize(1 to 20, 5)
```

Executing `rdd.glom.collect` will print:

```scala
Array[Array[Int]] = Array(
   Array(1, 2, 3, 4), 
   Array(5, 6, 7, 8),
   Array(9, 10, 11, 12), 
   Array(13, 14, 15, 16),
   Array(17, 18, 19, 20)
)
```

Where each inner array's position is its partition number.
E.g `Array(1, 2, 3, 4)` belongs to zeroth partition, `Array(5, 6, 7, 8)` to first partition, etc.

Comment: Can I pick which partition I want by index instead of outputting all of them, and save this output to a val?