# Take part of rdd and keep it rdd

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I can't find a way to take just a part on `rdd`. `take` seems promising but it returns a `list` instead of `rdd`. I of course can then convert it to an `rdd`, but this seems wasteful and ugly.

```py
 my_rdd = sc.textFile("my_file.csv")
 part_of_my_rdd = sc.parallelize(my_rdd.take(10000))
```

I there a better way to do this?

Comment: You can also get a single partition using  mapPartitionsWithIndex http://stackoverflow.com/a/32520254/2843520

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, indeed there is a better way. You can use the [sample](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=rdd#pyspark.RDD.sample) method from `RDD`s, it states:

> sample(withReplacement, fraction, seed=None)
>
> Return a sampled subset of this RDD.

```py
quantity = 10000
my_rdd = sc.textFile("my_file.csv")
part_of_my_rdd = my_rdd.sample(False, quantity / my_rdd.count())
```

Comment: Thanks, there had to be something!

Comment: Kind of works but no guarantee to get 10k entries and you still read the whole file. Maybe author doesn't care.

Answer (score 0):

@Akavall , it is a good idea. but the format have some change.

```
my_rdd = sc.textFile("my_file.csv")
part_of_my_rdd = sc.parallelize(my_rdd.take(10000)).map(x=>x.slice(1, x.length-1))
```

remove the brackets is OK!