# how can we get a sample of each partition of a dataframe in pyspark?

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, partitioning

I am experimenting with repartitioning of a dataframe in pyspark and out of curiosity I wanted to get a sample of rows from each partition just to see how it works. Ideally we would have a function that accepts a dataframe, the index of the partition and a sample fraction (e.g. 0.1 would return 10% of the rows in the partition) and returns the corresponding smaller dataframe.

I have seen in scala that mapPartitionsWithIndex can be used for the underlying RDD ([How to get data from a specific partition in Spark RDD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32517976/how-to-get-data-from-a-specific-partition-in-spark-rdd)) but I could not figure how to do this pyspark (by reading https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.RDD.mapPartitionsWithIndex.html?highlight=mappartition#pyspark.RDD.mapPartitionsWithIndex). How exactly does this function work? Or there is a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `mapPartitionsWithIndex`, I found a simple solution using the function [`spark_partition_id`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.spark_partition_id.html).
Below you can find a short example.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

# create example dataframe with numbers from 1 to 100
df = spark.createDataFrame([tuple([1 + n]) for n in range(100)], ['number'])
df.rdd.getNumPartitions()   # => 8



# custom function to sample rows within partitions
def resample_in_partition(df, fraction, partition_col_name='partition_id', seed=42):
  
  # create dictionary of sampling fractions per `partition_col_name`
  fractions = df\
    .select(partition_col_name)\
    .distinct()\
    .withColumn('fraction', F.lit(fraction))\
    .rdd.collectAsMap()
  
  # stratified sampling
  sampled_df = df.stat.sampleBy(partition_col_name, fractions, seed)

  return sampled_df



df = df.withColumn('partition_id', F.spark_partition_id())
df = resample_in_partition(df, fraction=0.1)

df.show()

+------+------------+
|number|partition_id|
+------+------------+
|     8|           0|
|    22|           1|
|    44|           3|
|    49|           4|
|    50|           4|
|    57|           4|
|    64|           5|
|    86|           7|
+------+------------+
```

Since my dataframe is small, the approximate resampling can give different numbers of rows for each partition. With large dataset, this problem should be less visible.

Comment: I also managed to get it working with `mapPartitionsWithIndex`, and the results are the same with the ones produced with the solution provided by @Ric (that is a better solution in my view). Details at https://gist.github.com/karpanGit/1036c50b0a06347e7dad424d7a594f90

Comment: @karpan Glad I could help :) Please consider accepting the answer (by clicking the tick under the votes) if you found it useful!

Comment: Sure @RicS. I accepted the answer. Thanks once more for your help.