# PySpark: Taking elements of a particular RDD partition

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to print/take elements of a particular partition. On [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30077425/how-to-print-elements-of-particular-rdd-partition-in-spark), I've found an elegant way to do it in Scala using this code:

```
distData.mapPartitionsWithIndex( (index: Int, it: Iterator[Int]) =>it.toList.map(x => if (index ==5) {println(x)}).iterator).collect
```

I'm struggling in converting this to Python, can you someone help me out here.

P.S: Also, unlike the above solution, I just want to take first 5 elements of the partition, instead of printing it all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

```
from itertools import islice

rdd.mapPartitions(lambda it: islice(it, 0, 5))
```

or

```
rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex(lambda i, it: islice(it, 0, 5) if i == x else [])
```

Comment: Missed `withIndex`